# Missing PHP Session in .html file

Tags: php, html, session, webserver

I'm trying to migrate a Webshop to a new Webserver. It is working perfectly fine on the old Webserver, however, when I try to login at the Webshop (index.html) it returns to the homepage, not logged in as the Session Variable is empty. 
Then I noticed, when I opened another Site called request.php) the Session Variable was set and I was logged in.
So I tried several things, I renamed the index.html to index.php and the session was there.

My question is now: Can I get the Session in .html files, too (as on the previous Webserver) or do I have to rename all my .html files?

Note: The index.html file contains php code as well and is parsed as php, just the session variable is empty.

Thanks in advance for every answer!

Comment: It seems that on the old server the html files were also were configured as php executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a Apache Server, try add this to the config file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: it is not the best idea to use html files to run any type of server-side scripts.
if you are able to, you should rename the html files with php, to php instead, its also less confusing, when you need to edit them, as most editors do not color-code php in a html file.

Comment: Okay, so I will rename my index.html and also change all links to that file. Still I wonder why the session variable is empty since php is parsed the same way as in a .php file.

Comment: Since there are no other answers, I'm gonna mark this as solved although I don't really now the reason why it works with .php ending.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a handler in your web server to treat `html` files as `php` files.

Comment: I guess thats Droa's answer, the php code in index.html is parsed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The files need to be renamed to have a .php extension on them, even if they include html. 
Simply include your php code before the html starts, like so:

```
<?php
 //code goes here
?>

<html>
  <body>
    //etc...
```

This way, you can load up your session variable and any other PHP variables you need, then they'll be accessible in the html as well.

If you have several pages that will need the same thing (session variable), you could put the session code into a php file, something like 'session.php'.
Then, at the top of every page you're converting from html to php, put this code at the top:

```
<?php
  require_once("session.php");
?>
```

Now all of your pages will have access to the same information, and it helps to cut down on the code too.

Comment: Including the php code before the html starts is exactly what my index.html file is doing. The only difference is the ending of the file (index.html, index.php)

Answer (score 0):

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

In your .htaccess file will do the job, still I believe it's rather **unsafe** to do it :)

Comment: That did not do the trick, maybe I was not clear about that, the .html file contains php code which gets parsed. It's just that the variable containing the session is empty.

Comment: didn't you forget about session_start() in that .html file then?

Comment: no, the index.html and the request.php both include another .php file which does the session initialization (session_start() ). If this was missing it wouldn't have worked on the old webserver anyway.