# I have an issue with the session variable in remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am a starter in PHP language. I was trying to develop a small application. For that (lets say, page 1) I was posting some data to a PHP file from the page 1 through an Ajax call.Then I want to access the same value from that PHP file in another HTML file through another Ajax call (let's call page 2).

So I used the session variable for this. I was able to access the values easily in my local-host. Then I uploaded  the files in my hosting server. But the application is not working. From the page 1 the data is sending and I am getting the Ajax response accordingly. but am not getting the data in the page2.

Page 1 code is as follows

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'main.php', 
                data: {type : 'test' },
                dataType:'html', 
                success: function (data) { 
                            location.assign("mains.html");  


                }
         });
    return true;     
});

</script>
```

page 2 is as follows

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $( document ).ready(function() {


        $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
               url: 'main.php', 
                data: { test: 'value' }, 
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) { 
                                alert(data);

                }
         });

    });

</script>
```

the server file is as following,(of course its a PHP file)

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['type'])){


$_SESSION['type'] = $type = $_GET['type'];

echo $_SESSION['type'];

}

if(isset($_GET['test'])){

echo $_SESSION['type'];


}

echo $_SESSION['type'];
?>
```

Comment: Are your localhost and the remote server configured identically? Check that they're both handling sessions the same way.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I don't know how to check it. Could you please advise me on that

Answer (score 1):

Change the extension of your HTML file to .php, then start the file with

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

In other words: session_start() needs to be called in every PHP file you use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am using only one php file. all of the rest are html pages. I am developing a simple application with html pages. And i will take the data using json object and will display the data in the correct place using simple java script/jquery. I have used the session_start() in the starting of the php file. Please check the last block of codes

Comment: **@Mathew** Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186458/missing-php-session-in-html-file